# ggplot2 multi-variable scatterplot, Changing Labels and View in Margins

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatterplot based on four values. My data is just lists of prices (BASIC,VALUE,DELUXE,ULTIMATE). I want VALUE and DELUXE to be the two axis (x,y) and then have the size and color of the points represent the data for the other two columns.

It is hard to set up a reproducible example, because it is only an issue when I get a lot of values listed. i have about 300 points, with about 30 different color/value labels(For ULTIMATE, and 20 size/value labels(For BASIC)

```
> gg <- ggplot(d, aes(x=DELUXE_PRICE, y=VALUE_PRICE,color=ULTIMATE_PRICE,size=BASIC_PRICE)) + geom_point(alpha = 1)
> plot(gg)
```

My code does this well, and lists the colors/size with the corresponding value on the side. This is great, but I would like to alter how that is displayed, so that it is not cut off. I would like to be able to "wrap" the values into more columns, or shrink the display size of those so that they fit.

Currently, this lists ULTIMATE in three columns, to the right of the plot area, but cuts off the top of the labels (it extends well above the plot area)

This lists BASIC size/value labels to the right of the plot area, below ULTIMATE labels, in one column, so about half are cut off at the bottom.

I can increase the margins with:

```
> gg <- ggplot(d, aes(x=DELUXE_PRICE, y=VALUE_PRICE,color=ULTIMATE_PRICE,size=BASIC_PRICE)) + geom_point(alpha = 1) +theme(plot.margin = unit(c(4,2,4,2), "cm"))
> plot(gg)
```

This gets more of it in, but creates lots of white area and a smaller view of the plot. I would like to be able to just increase the right margin if necessary, and "wrap" the labels in more columns extending to the right. (i.e. put ULTIMATE into 4 columns instead of 3, and put BASIC into 3-4 columns instead of 1 - So that they are shorter and don't run out the plot area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some built in functionality I found to do the required operation. It lies in adding a guides() argument to the plot, specifying whether I am dealing with the color or size legend, and specifying the number of columns with "ncol = " (You can also specify rows). Giving it an order ranking allows you to rank these as well, so my resulting code was:

```
> gg <- ggplot(Table, aes(x=DELUXE_PRICE, y=VALUE_PRICE,color=ULTIMATE_PRICE,size=BASIC_PRICE)) + geom_point(alpha = 1) + guides(color = guide_legend(order = 0,ncol = 4),size = guide_legend(order = 1,ncol = 4))
```